# On mouse hover in slick.js sliding do not stop immediately

Tags: slick.js

When I set `speed: 1000`, `pauseOnHover` is working fine but as soon as I set  it to `speed: 10000`, `pauseOnHover` does not work immediately - it works after a few seconds.

Code:

```
$('#featured_credits').slick({
      infinite: true,
      arrows: true,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 0,
      speed: 1000,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      pauseOnHover: true,
      pauseOnFocus: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      accessibility: false,
      mobileFirst: true
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/415)**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/415/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are right @Rohit, Actually I think it is stop slide after the time you have entered in speed, bit better when I change speed to `speed: 500` and `slidesToScroll: 0.5` so it is stop in 0.5 mili second and scroll half slide in 0.5 mili second, [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/fmo50w7n/3952/)

Note: It is the temporary solution when I come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is.. When you hover on slides the in-between slides in current frame reaches to left most (when slides moving from right to left) it stops then . It doesn't do anything with setting speed and slidesToScroll. It feels like it working with `speed:500` and `slideToScroll: 0.5` is because with that speed by the time you hover and you feel the slide is paused, the above mentioned scenario is happened(slides in current frame reaches to left most).